# Correct way of binding to a model that represents no backend resource

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have created a search screen and bind the user selection to a model.

```
//SortDetails
export default DS.Model.extend({
 orderBy: DS.attr('string'),
 orderDirection: DS.attr('string'),
 startDate: DS.attr('date'),
 endDate: DS.attr('date')
});
```

Now once the user clicks the search button each of these fields gets passed through to the queryString and sent to the server.

```
this.store.find('item', {
     orderBy: sortDetails.get('orderBy'),
     orderDirection: sortDetails.get('orderDirection'),
     startDate: sortDetails.get('startDate'),
     endDate: sortDetails.get('endDate'),
});
```

Is this the correct way of doing this sort of thing?  This model does not represent any backend resource.  I can see in ember-inspector that new models are being created and just hang around which might be a performance problem for a long running application.

Comment: Why don't you just use an Ember.Object instead of an DS.Model?

Comment: @BavoVanGeit yep maybe that is a better solution.  I assume you can pass these around using transitionTo().  I will try it out tomorrow.